# Summing up the rows

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

[image]

I want to add up the profit of all the rows where 1.a=2.a && 1.b=2.b && 1.c=2.c ( The case in first and second row , also in third and fourth ). I wrote the following query but this isn't working .

**db.Execute "UPDATE a,b,c,SUM(profit) FROM Sum ORDER BY a"**

Query execution gives an error. Here is a sample data, be it six records with four fields each.

```
ID | a | b | c | d
==================
   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 50 
   | 1 | 1 | 1 |100 
   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 54 
   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 46 
   | 1 | 2 | 4 | 50 
   | 1 | 1 | 2 |100
```

The expected result set is 4 records with last 2 being the same

```
ID | a | b | c | d 
   | 1 | 1 | 1 |150 
   | 1 | 2 | 3 |100 
   | 1 | 2 | 4 | 50
   | 1 | 1 | 2 |100
```

Comment: Your update statement is wrong. You shall write `"update Sum set myCol = (select sum(profit) from myTable where myConditionForUnicity) where myOtherCondition"`. What is this error you're getting?

Comment: Thanks . I am getting an error in the condition part when I use " ORDER BY a " saying the field a is not a part of aggregate function .

Comment: It does not make sense to order an update query. Also, it does not seem to be possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735950/update-with-order-by

Comment: Any other logic that can be applied ?

Comment: When I copy all these records to another table .Only the first instance of a particular combination is copied . For E.g. only 1st is copied from 1st and 2nd , only 3rd is copied from 3rd and 4th , and  5th and 6th are both copied . What I am trying to do is to add profit of ist and 2nd but I am only getting profit of 1st . I think I nned to update the profit before i copy the recordsm in to another table

Comment: @user3504466: `a is not part of an aggregate function` means that you need to `GROUP BY a, b, c` before you may even `ORDER BY a`. Generally speaking, I agree with @AlexandrePLevasseur, it doesn't sound good to order by along with an update statement. Please provide us with further details: **sample data** and **expected result set**.

Comment: Ok thanks. You can see the sample data in the picture and I am not able to upload a picture of the resuly set but i can explain it . It should have 4 records with 1st having a profit of 150 , second having a profit of 100 and 3rd and 4th are same as 5th and 6th in the sample dataset .

Comment: http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1DnN1mMPbNVNKTEupyHnLJa2VFGrBQ0

Comment: @user3504466: Unfortunately, I can't see the image because of network security policies. A small table with two or three lines of data can be useful.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller: I have edited the question . It is diffiult to draw a table . I have seperated all the records by colon : thanks

Comment: Is this not simply a matter of "SELECT a,b,c,SUM(Profit) FROM tbl GROUP BY a,b,c" ?

Comment: @Matt: I guess you're right. After seeing the data samples, I do think the OP needs a select statement.

Comment: @user3504466: I edited your question to illustrate the tables. Please edit accordingly if any change are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a simple SELECT query:

```
SELECT a,b,c,SUM(Profit) 
FROM tableName 
GROUP BY a,b,c
ORDER BY a
```

Comment: If you must execute from VBA, I would suggest creating the query in Access, and then executing the query from code.

Comment: +1 @Matt: I added the `ORDER BY` clause as required by the OP in his question. =)