# update a queryset in a specific order

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a "index" field stores a consequent range of integers, for safety i set it unique.

now I want to increase this field by one, to keep unique I update the value in a descending order:

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by('-index').update(index=F('index')+1)
```

what surprises me is that **on some machine** an IntegrityError
gets raised and complains for duplicated index value.

is there anything i missed? could I only save records one by one?

thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**:

I think the root problem is that **there is no ORDER BY in an SQL UPDATE command** (see [UPDATE with ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735950/update-with-order-by), and also [SQL Server: UPDATE a table by using ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439110/sql-server-update-a-table-by-using-order-by))

Obviously django simply translates my statement into a SQL UPDATE with ORDER_BY, which leads to an undefined behavior and creates different result per machine.

Answer (score 1):

You are ordering the queryset ascending. You can make it descending by adding the '-' to the field name in the order by:

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by('-index').update(index=F('index')+1)
```

[Django docs for order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)