# Conditional unique constraint not updating correctly

Tags: postgresql

I need to enforce uniqueness on a column but only when other column is true. For example:

```
create temporary table test(id serial primary key, property character varying(50), value boolean);
insert into test(property, value) values ('a', false);
insert into test(property, value) values ('a', true);
insert into test(property, value) values ('a', false);
```

And I enforce the uniqueness with a conditional index:

```
create unique index on test(property) where value = true;
```

So far so good, the problem arises when I try to change the row that has the value set to true. It works if I do:

```
update test set value = new_value from (select id, id=3 as new_value from test where property = 'a')new_test where test.id = new_test.id
```

But it doesn't when I do:

```
update test set value = new_value from (select id, id=1 as new_value from test where property = 'a')new_test where test.id = new_test.id
```

And I get:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_property_idx"
DETAIL:  Key (property)=(a) already exists.

********** Error **********

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_property_idx"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (property)=(a) already exists.
```

Basically it works if the row with value true has a primary key with a bigger value than the current row which is truthy. Any idea on how to circumvent it?

Of course I could do:

```
update test set value = false where property='a';
update test set value = true where property = 'a' and id = 1;
```

However, I'm running these queries from node and it is preferable to run only one query.

I'm using Postgres 9.5

Comment: Try to make the unique constraint DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED.  Not sure for the syntax unfortunately.

Comment: Seems actually that it is not possible with UNIQUE INDEX, only with CONSTRAINT UNIQUE

Comment: Use stored function to update the data. `update test set value = false where property='a' and value;` would be more efficient. BTW `update test set value = id = 3 where property = 'a';` is simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that [`UPDATE` statements cannot have an `ORDER BY` clause in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735950/update-with-order-by) (it can have in some RDBMS, but not in PostgreSQL).

The usual solution to this is to make the constraint deferrable. But you use a partial unique index & indexes cannot be declared as deferrable.

Use an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) instead: they are the generalization of unique constraints & can be partial too.

```
ALTER TABLE test
  ADD EXCLUDE (property WITH =) WHERE (value = true)
  DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```