# Error "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" while updating multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I created a table in PostgreSQL and Oracle as

```
CREATE TABLE temp(
   seqnr smallint NOT NULL,
   defn_id int not null,
   attr_id int not null,
   input CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (defn_id, attr_id, seqnr)
);
```

This temp table has primary key as (defn_id,attr_id,seqnr) as a whole!

Then I inserted the record in the temp table as

```
INSERT INTO temp(seqnr,defn_id,attr_id,input)
VALUES (1,100,100,'test1');

INSERT INTO temp(seqnr,defn_id,attr_id,input)
VALUES (2,100,100,'test2');

INSERT INTO temp(seqnr,defn_id,attr_id,input)
VALUES (3,100,100,'test3');

INSERT INTO temp(seqnr,defn_id,attr_id,input)
VALUES (4,100,100,'test4');

INSERT INTO temp(seqnr,defn_id,attr_id,input)
VALUES (5,100,100,'test5');
```

in both Oracle and Postgres!
The table now contains:

```
 seqnr |  defn_id | attr_id | input
     1 |      100 |    100  | test1
     2 |      100 |    100  | test2
     3 |      100 |    100  | test3
     4 |      100 |    100  | test4
     5 |      100 |    100  | test5
```

When I run the command:

```
UPDATE temp SET seqnr=seqnr+1
WHERE defn_id = 100 AND attr_id = 100 AND seqnr >= 1;
```

In case of ORACLE it is Updating 5 Rows and the O/p is

```
 seqnr |  defn_id | attr_id | input
     2 |      100 |    100  | test1
     3 |      100 |    100  | test2
     4 |      100 |    100  | test3
     5 |      100 |    100  | test4
     6 |      100 |    100  | test5
```

But in case of PostgreSQL it is giving an error!

> ```
> DETAIL:  Key (defn_id, attr_id, seqnr)=(100, 100, 2) already exists.
> ```

Why does this happen and how can I replicate the same result in Postgres as Oracle?
Or how can the same result be achieved in Postgres without any errors?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping this in a transaction?  You can see why this happens, I presume.  When it tried to update row 1, there's already a row with `seqnr==2`.  Perhaps if you make it a transaction, it can do the whole chunk at once.

Comment: BEGIN;
UPDATE temp SET seqnr=seqnr+1 WHERE defn_id = 100 AND attr_id = 100 AND seqnr >= 1;
COMMIT;   tried but same error persists!

Comment: Also why it is not the Case with Oracle? In oracle it is allowing me to update without any unique constrain violation Error!

Comment: Unrelated, but: [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29) (this is a bad choice in Oracle as well)

Comment: This is because Oracle and Postgres validate a unique constraint differently. The usual solution in Postgres is to define the unique constraint as deferrable. But then you can't define a foreign key to that PK any more. Not sure if that is a problem in your case or not. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8f6ef832faef38b39823abf23777dfdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNIQUE` an `PRIMARY KEY` constraints are checked immediately (for each row) unless they are defined **`DEFERRABLE`** - which is the solution you demand.

```sql
ALTER TABLE temp
  DROP CONSTRAINT pk_id
, ADD  CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (defn_id, attr_id, seqnr) DEFERRABLE
;
```

Then your `UPDATE` just works.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d68f94ccc503ebdd17e28df69b7f6c46)*

This comes at a **cost**, though. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> Note that deferrable constraints cannot be used as conflict
> arbitrators in an `INSERT` statement that includes an `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` clause.

And [for `FOREIGN KEY` constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> The referenced columns must be the columns of a non-deferrable unique
> or primary key constraint in the referenced table.

[And:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.9.4)

> When a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint is not deferrable,
> PostgreSQL checks for uniqueness immediately whenever a row is
> inserted or modified. The SQL standard says that uniqueness should be
> enforced only at the end of the statement; this makes a difference
> when, for example, a single command updates multiple key values. To
> obtain standard-compliant behavior, declare the constraint as
> `DEFERRABLE` but not deferred (i.e., `INITIALLY IMMEDIATE`). Be aware
> that this can be significantly slower than immediate uniqueness
> checking.

See:

- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032272/constraint-defined-deferrable-initially-immediate-is-still-deferred)

I would **avoid** a `DEFERRABLE` PK if at all possible. Maybe you can work around the demonstrated problem? This *usually* works:

```sql
UPDATE temp t
SET    seqnr = t.seqnr + 1
FROM  (
   SELECT defn_id, attr_id, seqnr
   FROM   temp
   WHERE  defn_id = 100 AND attr_id = 100 AND seqnr >= 1
   ORDER  BY defn_id, attr_id, seqnr DESC
   ) o
WHERE (t.defn_id, t.attr_id, t.seqnr)
    = (o.defn_id, o.attr_id, o.seqnr);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d68f94ccc503ebdd17e28df69b7f6c46)*

But there are no guarantees as `ORDER BY` is not specified for `UPDATE` in Postgres.

Related:

- [UPDATE with ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735950/update-with-order-by/16737506#16737506)

Comment: They have an additional drawback: a deferrable primary key can also not be used as the target of a foreign key.

Comment: i have defn_id and attr_id  as foreign key in another tables! so will that cause an issue?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, important restriction. I added another quote from the manual. And a possible workaround for the `UPDATE`.

Comment: @anant: you can't have only defn_id and attr_id as foreign keys - your foreign key must include **all** columns of the primary key

Comment: @anant: I suspect your FK constraints actually point in the other direction (and that is not impaired either way), wouldn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: UPDATE temp SET seqnr = (seqnr + 1) * -1
WHERE defn_id = 100 AND attr_id = 100;
UPDATE temp SET seqnr = seqnr * -1
WHERE  defn_id = 100 AND attr_id = 100
AND   seqnr < 0;