# PHP - Postgresql How I can rollback a query if is returning error?

Tags: php, postgresql, auto-increment

I'm making a CRUD with php and postgres, and I want to know if there a way to rollback the transaction if there is a error.
actually if I get an error in the transaction the id (primary key) get increased, then I lose one id for the future use.

How can I prevent it? I mean, if the Insert's Query fails, don't make the auto increment in the table.

Im using a class for execute the querys:

```
public function insertRecord ($data){
        $campos =$this->getTableFields();
        $data =implode ("', '", $data);
        $sql ="INSERT INTO {$this->table} ($campos) VALUES (";
        $sysData =$this->getDefaultValues();
        if($sysData){
            $sysData .= ",";
            $sql .="$sysData ";
        }
        $sql .="'$data') RETURNING {$this->campoId};";
        echo $sql;
        pg_query($this->linkid,$sql);
        return $this->validateOperation();
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [Transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html).

Comment: @tyteen4a03, i read about it, but i ask, i have a class called PG, where i put all the statements (Inserts,updates,selects,deletes) and then i have separate class for the table's use (articles, art_mov, art_warehouse), and in every class i call the statements passing the table and the conditions,  Given it, i must to make in every class the sql statements? because in every table i don't make the same query - Right now i don't know how explain my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction is rolled back. But it will still use up a number from a sequence, on which automatically incrementing values are based. This is by design and prevents long lasting locks, which would kill parallel execution performance.

There are some workarounds:

- [postgresql generate sequence with no gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004453/postgresql-generate-sequence-with-no-gap)

Comment: Well i made another questions, and this comment answers the both questions, well i guess i need improve another column if i wanna create a manual sequence (to show a pretty number) Thanks a lot @Tometzky