# Spring data JPA: primary key not sequentially auto incrementing

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, primary-key

In spring data jpa Application I created one model with @entity annotation. I am saving that model data into table. I am auto incrementing primary key. But when I am saving data into table it's not sequentially auto incrementing.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Class file:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="exception")
public class Exception implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "exception_seq_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "exception_seq_generator", sequenceName = "exception_seq")
    @Column(name="exception_id")
    public Integer exceptionId;
    
    @Column(name="status_code")
    public Integer statusCode;
    
    public String message;
    public String status;
    public String error;
    //Getter and setter
```

Table:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why the primary key is not auto incrementing sequentially? Why it's not taking 2,3,4.....

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the sequence `exception_seq`? This one is defined in the database.

Comment: Use the IDENTITY strategy `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` and if you are auto generating your schema `@Column(name="exception_id", columnDefinition="serial")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postgresql generate sequence with no gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004453/postgresql-generate-sequence-with-no-gap)

Answer (score 2):

First of all try setting the **allocationSize**:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "exception_seq_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "exception_seq_generator", sequenceName = "exception_seq", allocationSize=1)
@Column(name="exception_id")
public Integer exceptionId;
```

Also check your current Sequence in the Database, it might have a wrong value now.

**Simpler aproach:**

Define the primary-key column in PostgreSQL DB as SERIAL:

```
CREATE TABLE xy (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
);
```

And annotate the Column with:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

The [SERIAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) type, creates an auto-increment sequence for you and you don't have that much overhead in you JPA Entities.